# Как запросить данные с PostgreSQL в обратном порядке

Tags: javascript, node.js

Для получения данных с БД PostgreSQL я использую данный код:

```
async getAll(req, res){                                          //get all and get filtered (by need) by manufacturer, body type
    let {manufacturerId, carNameId,limit,page} = req.query
    page = page || 1
    limit = limit || 100
    let offset = page * limit - limit                                 //skip limit cars on next page
    let cars;
    if (!manufacturerId && !carNameId){                                          //get all
        cars = await Car.findAndCountAll({limit, offset})                           //for knowing total cars amount use findAndCountAll() instead of findAll() - for pagination
    }
    if (manufacturerId && !carNameId){                                                          //filtering by manufacturer
        cars = await Car.findAndCountAll({where: {manufacturerId}, limit, offset})
    }
    if (!manufacturerId && carNameId){                                          //filtering by car name
        cars = await Car.findAndCountAll({where: {carNameId}, limit, offset})
    }
    if (manufacturerId && carNameId){                                           //filtering by car name and manufacturer
        cars = await Car.findAndCountAll({where: {carNameId,manufacturerId}, limit, offset})
    }
    return res.json(cars)
}
```

Здесь идет запрос текущей страницы пользователя и количество отображаемых на странице элементов, далее - фильтрация.

Мне нужно отображение элементов в обратном порядке. **Чтобы на клиент приходил уже перевернутый JSON**. Не совсем понимаю как это сделать правильно.

Мои попытки привели меня только к обратному порядку на странице. Условно: на странице не с 1 по 10 а с 10 по 1.

Цель: если на странице по 10 элементов, а всего в БД 100 элементов, то на первой странице должен быть с 100 по 90 элемент

Comment: В вашей орм должен быть метод `orderBy` копайте туда

Comment: а как определяется порядок-то? по дате добавления, по цвету, по имени...? и покажите код метода findAndCountAll

Comment: Думаю, что вы используете `Sequelize`, тогда вот пример использования `order` https://stackoverflow.com/a/36260326/4711135

Comment: все верно, я использую Sequelize, спасибо большое !